# Assigning one object's fields from another before nulling the first object

Tags: c#, reference

I have an instance of a class that is about to be nulled out (objA = null). Before that happens I want to copy the fields of that object into another instance that I will save (objB).

If I do the following will objB keep its values after objA is null.

```
objB.field1 = objA.field1;
objB.field2 = objA.field2;
objB.innerClass = objA.innerClass;
```

Then later...

```
objA = null;
```

What if one of the fields is a reference type instead of a value type? Will that make a difference?

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily tested. I have an example (SomeProp is an `int?`):

```
private int? Q = 5;

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyClass a = new MyClass();
    a.SomeProp = Q;
    MyClass b = new MyClass();
    b.SomeProp = a.SomeProp;
    a = null;
    MessageBox.Show( b.SomeProp.ToString() ); //Outputs 5
    Q = null;
    MessageBox.Show( b.SomeProp.ToString() ); //Still outputs 5
}
```

I tried exactly the same code but using string, no difference in output.

Answer (score 0):

Primitives (Value Types) will have memory allocated.

A Reference type will have an address in memory.  When you assign another Reference type a value from another object, that value will just point to the address in memory.

After setting an Reference type to null, any pointer to that address will return null.

A good explanation can be found here:
[Primitive Types and Reference Types](http://www.introprogramming.info/english-intro-csharp-book/read-online/chapter-2-primitive-types-and-variables/)